# Create a constant set collection of strings c++

Tags: c++, stl

This might sound like a basic question, and it's certainly solvable but i'm looking for a quick and elegant solution.

I want to create a collection of reserved words for my program:
`{"apple", "orange", "peach"}`

It is constant and i want to be able during runtime to check if a string `s` is a reserved word (f `s` is part of the set).

I've thought about using `std::set` but i don't want to add each one of my reserved words to the set manually. Besides, I don't need the full power of set, for example I don't need to add new elements or to remove ones.

What is an elegant way of doing it ?

Comment: If you don't want a `std::set` to represent a set, use an array and `std::find`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the words in an array, then use the `std::set` range constructor:

```
char const* raw_words[] = { "apple", "orange", "peach" };

std::set<std::string> const words(std::begin(raw_words), std::end(raw_words));
```

This makes use of the new `begin` and `end` functions in C++11, but you can also do this in C++03 using pointers to the first and one-past-the-end elements of the array.

In C++11 you could also use an initializer list to initialize the `std::set`, though not all compilers support this feature yet.

Note also that if the contents of the set of words never change, it might be better to simply use a sorted `std::vector<std::string>` with `std::lower_bound` and `std::binary_search` to find elements.  You may find that this will perform better.

Comment: This is what I need. Was trying to do this with a string array instead of `char *`. Thanks.

Comment: `std::string raw_words[]` would work fine too.  I picked `char const*` to avoid the unnecessary overhead of `std::string`.  Since the only use of `raw_words` is to initialize `words`, there's no need for the features of `std::string` there.

Answer (score 6):

in modern c++ (c++11):

```
const std::set<std::string> v = { "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" };
```

Comment: Neither `std::set` nor `std::string` are `constexpr`-friendly: https://godbolt.org/g/CmvaZa - You should **delete your answer** to avoid spreading misinformation.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I replaced `constexpr` by `const`

Answer (score 2):

> i don't want to add each one of my reserved words to the set manually.

If by that you mean you don't want code that looks like:

```
reserved_word.insert("apple");
reserved_word.insert("orange");
reserved_word.insert("peach");
```

in some initialization code that has to run before everything else, you can instead do (in C++11):

```
const std::set<std::string> reserved_word = {"apple", "orange", "peach"};
```

Although this does still perform initialization at run-time.

You could also simply use a pre-sorted `char const *reserved_word[] = { ... }`. This would avoid the need for any run-time initialization at all. Though you'd better get the sorting right in your source code, or you will get unexpected behavior when you try to search it for a word using one of the sorted sequence search algorithms.

> Besides, I don't need the full power of set

I don't believe that's a good reason to avoid it. A better reason to avoid something is if it allows things that you want to disallow. For example if you actually want to prevent adding and removing things then using a non-const set would not be the best option. But since you can use a const set instead there's no need to avoid set.